# Microsoft Sway doesn't auto refresh at previously shared/displaying embed code

Tags: ms-office, office365-apps

In Microsoft Sway :
I have made presentation on **MS Sway**. Used it's embed code to share.
Now, after changing or updating the content of that presentation it **doesn't reflect/refresh new changes automatically on the shared page (until it is refreshed manually)**. 
Its needed to **refresh manually** to see the new changes.

Can any one please help me if you have faced same concern. 
Or is it MS-Sway way to doing it (i.e. we do not have control).